# передача данных на сервер в формате JSON

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте! У меня есть два варианта сбор данных с формы, для отправки на сервер: с помощью функции `serialize()` и с помощью формата JSON. Первый вариант работает, второй не работает.

***1 вариант, с помощью функции serialize()***

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>New Страница</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Калькулятор</legend>
   <input id="number1" type="text" name="number1" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <select id="sign" name="sign">
    <option value="choose" selected="selected">выберите</option>
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
    <option value="%">%</option>
   </select>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="number2" type="text" name="number2" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="button1" type="button" name="button1" value="=" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="result" type="text" name="result" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="button2" type="button" name="button2" value="очистить" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 <h4></h4>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  /*кнопка =*/
  $('#button1').click(function () {
   //сбор данных с формы, для отправки на сервер
   var obj = $('form').serialize();
   //запрос к серверу без перезагрузки страницы
   $.ajax({
    url: 'a.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: obj,
    success: function (str) {
     $('h4').text('Yes!');
     //обращаемся к массиву по индексу
     $('#result').val(str[0]);
    },
    error: function (str) {
     $('h4').text('Error!');
    }
   });
  });

  /*кнопка очистить*/
  $('#button2').click(function () {
   //$('#number1').val('');
   //$('#number2').val('');
   //$('#result').val('');
   location.replace(document.URL);
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**a.php**

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

class Calculate {
 private $number1;
 private $number2;
 private $sign;
 function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
  $this->number1 = $arg1;
  $this->sign = $arg2;
  $this->number2 = $arg3;
 }
 public function funResult() {
  switch ($this->sign) {
   case '' :
    return null;
   break;
   case '+' :
    return $this->number1 + $this->number2;
   break;
   case '-' :
    return $this->number1 - $this->number2;
   break;
   case '*' :
    return $this->number1 * $this->number2;
   break;
   case '/' :
    if($this->number2 == 0) {
     return 'На 0 делить нельзя!';
    }
    else {
     return $this->number1 / $this->number2;
    }
   break;
   case '%' :
    if($this->number2 == 0) {
     return 'На 0 делить нельзя!';
    }
    else {
     return $this->number1 % $this->number2;
    }
   break;
  }
 }
}

//данные пришли на сервер
$a = (float)$_POST['number1'];
$sign = $_POST['sign'];
$b = (float)$_POST['number2'];

//что-то делаем на сервере с этими данными
$C = new Calculate($a, $sign, $b);

//помещаем строку в массив
$ara = array($C->funResult());

//кодируем массив в строку формата JSON
$str = json_encode($ara);

//возрващаем строку в формате JSON
echo $str;
```

***2 вариант, с помощью формата JSON***

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>New Страница</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Калькулятор</legend>
   <input id="number1" type="text" name="number1" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <select id="sign" name="sign">
    <option value="choose" selected="selected">выберите</option>
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
    <option value="%">%</option>
   </select>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="number2" type="text" name="number2" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="button1" type="button" name="button1" value="=" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="result" type="text" name="result" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="button2" type="button" name="button2" value="очистить" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 <h4></h4>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  /*кнопка =*/
  $('#button1').click(function () {
   //сбор данных с формы, для отправки на сервер
   //var obj = $('form').serialize();
   var obj = {
    a: $('#number1').val(),
    sign: $('#sign').val(),
    b: $('#number2').val()
   }
   //запрос к серверу без перезагрузки страницы
   $.ajax({
    url: 'a.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: obj,
    success: function (str) {
     $('h4').text('Yes!');
     //обращаемся к массиву по индексу
     $('#result').val(str[0]);
    },
    error: function (str) {
     $('h4').text('Error!');
    }
   });
  });

  /*кнопка очистить*/
  $('#button2').click(function () {
   //$('#number1').val('');
   //$('#number2').val('');
   //$('#result').val('');
   location.replace(document.URL);
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**a.php**

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

class Calculate {
 private $number1;
 private $number2;
 private $sign;
 function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
  $this->number1 = $arg1;
  $this->sign = $arg2;
  $this->number2 = $arg3;
 }
 public function funResult() {
  switch ($this->sign) {
   case '' :
    return null;
   break;
   case '+' :
    return $this->number1 + $this->number2;
   break;
   case '-' :
    return $this->number1 - $this->number2;
   break;
   case '*' :
    return $this->number1 * $this->number2;
   break;
   case '/' :
    if($this->number2 == 0) {
     return 'На 0 делить нельзя!';
    }
    else {
     return $this->number1 / $this->number2;
    }
   break;
   case '%' :
    if($this->number2 == 0) {
     return 'На 0 делить нельзя!';
    }
    else {
     return $this->number1 % $this->number2;
    }
   break;
  }
 }
}

//данные пришли на сервер
//ЗДЕСЬ ЧТО-ТО НУЖНО ИСПРАВИТЬ, ВОТ ТОЛЬКО ЧТО?
$a = (float)$_POST['number1'];
$sign = $_POST['sign'];
$b = (float)$_POST['number2'];

//что-то делаем на сервере с этими данными
$C = new Calculate($a, $sign, $b);

//помещаем строку в массив
$ara = array($C->funResult());

//кодируем массив в строку формата JSON
$str = json_encode($ara);

//возрващаем строку в формате JSON
echo $str;
```

Во втором варианте, в файле a.php что-то нужно исправить, возможно перекодировать, когда данные пришли на сервер. Я почему-то думал, что вот так

```
$a = (float)json_decode($_POST['number1']);
$sign = json_decode($_POST['sign']);
$b = (float)json_decode($_POST['number2']);
```

Но ничего не получается. Если кто знает, подскажите.

Comment: перед объявлением переменной `$C` вставьте `die($a.' - '.$sign.' - '.$b)` и посмотрите что возвращает php в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете в php `a: ..., b: ...`, а постом принимаете `number1, number2...`.

Решение:

Замена

```
$a = (float)$_POST['number1'];
$sign = $_POST['sign'];
$b = (float)$_POST['number2'];
```

На

```
$a = (float)$_POST['a'];
$sign = $_POST['sign'];
$b = (float)$_POST['b'];
```

Comment: Уважаемый mix! Я заменил. Ничего не работает. Я же написал, что проблема в файле a.php. Я специально показал два варианта. Специально написал полный код. Скопируйте к себе два последних файла и выполните. У Вас это работать будет или нет?

Comment: @Anton обновил ответ, причина была в другом.

Comment: Уважаемый mix! Вы совершенно правы! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = (float)$_POST['number1'];
$sign = $_POST['sign'];
$b = (float)$_POST['number2'];
```

у вас пост на сервер приходит.

Comment: Уважаемый Naumov, а что на сервер должно приходить?

Comment: @Anton $_POST[] запрос пост

Comment: Уважаемый Naumov! Скопируйте два последних файла и выполните у себя. Найдите ошибку в файле a.php. Напишите код с ошибкой и рядом напишите правильный код, который у Вас отработал. Это и будет полным правильным ответом. А то, что Вы пишите на ответ не тянет.